# Prove that this series diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n}$$

I'm not sure how to prove that the series diverges, I can see that the $n$'s are irrelevant and that the numerator will grow faster than the denominator, but I can't see how to prove it.

Comment: Hint: can you prove that the numerator is greater than the denominator?

Comment: There are many tests here: https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/MATH_3200%3A_Mathematical_Methods/Summary_Tables/Summary_of_Convergence_Tests

Comment: $\lim \frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n}\geq \lim \frac{n+2^n}{n+2^n}= \lim 1 = 1 \neq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that if $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies \displaystyle{\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n=0}$.
If we considere the general term and take the limit, we have:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \dfrac{n+3^n}{n+2^n} \sim \lim_{n \to +\infty} \dfrac{3^n}{2^n}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^n=+\infty
\end{equation}
Therefore, the series does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n}=\frac{\frac{n}{3^n}+1}{\frac{n}{3^n}+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n}.$$

Now $\frac{n}{3^n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, and as $0\leq\frac{2}{3}\leq1$, $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus the above is on the form $\left[\frac{1}{0}\right]$ (and in fact the limit is $\infty$). Thus, by the divergence test, as the limit is non-zero, the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

All of the terms are positive and they keep getting bigger.

If $\frac{1}{n} = q,$ then $\frac{p}{n+p} \gt q$ if $p \gt 1$.

So if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{2^{n}}$ diverges because its consecutive terms keep getting bigger, so does your sum.

Now, the proof concludes by oberving the following limit:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3^n}{2^{n}} = \infty. $$

Answer (score 0):

- $n+3^n>3^n$ since $n>0$
- $n+2^n<2\times 2^n$ since $n<2^n$

So $a_n>\frac 12 \left(\frac 32\right)^n$ which is a term of a divergent geometric series. Do not hesitate to search for rough inequalities for this kind of exercise before thinking of advanced methods, it reduces the difficulty tremendously.